# new to mercurial and VCS: shared code multi-server setup

Tags: version-control, mercurial, shared, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

In our small office we're setting up mercurial - our first time using a "real" version control system.  We've got three servers - a live server, a staging server and a development server.

We've also got three relatively large web sites - one for visitors, one for users and an intranet site, for the office staff.

The three web sites share some code. (for instance - a php class library, some commonly used code snippets, etc.)

Before version control, we just used symbolic links to link to the shared libraries.  For example: each site had a symbolic link to an "ObjectClasses" directory - any changes made to a file in ObjectClasses would be instantly available to all the sites.  You'd just upload the changed file to staging and to live, and you were done.

But... Mercurial doesn't follow symbolic links.  So I've set up a subrepository for the shared libraries in the three sites on the three servers (actually 'four' servers if you count the fact that there are two programmers with two separate clones of the repository on the development server).

So there are 12 working copies of the shared object library.

So here's the question:

Is there any way to simplify the above set up?

Here's an example of what our workflow will be and it seems too complicated - but maybe this is what it's like using version control and we just need to get used to it:

Programmer A makes a change to Object Foo in the subrepo in Site 1.  He wants to make this available everywhere, so he commits it, then pushes it to the staging server.  I set up hooks on the staging server to automatically propogate the changes to the three sites, on the staging server, and again to the three sites on the live server.  That takes care of the 6 working copies on the staging and live servers.  So far, so good.

but what about the development server, where there may be work-in-progress on these files?

Programmer A now needs to manually pull the shared subrepo to Sites 2 and 3 on the development server.  He also needs to tell Programmer B to manually pull the shared subrepo on Sites 1, 2 and 3 on his copy of the site on the development server.  What if he's editing Object Foo on Site 1 and making different edits to Object Foo on Site 2.  He's going to have to resolve two separate conflicts.

We make changes to the objects relatively frequently.  This is going to drive us nuts. I really love the idea of version control - but after two weeks of wrestling with trying to find the best setup, the old sloppy way of having one copy of the shared files and calling out "hey - ya working on that file, I wanna make a change" is looking pretty good right now.

Is there really no simpler way to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the specific web platform and technologies you're using (e.g., .NET, LAMP, ColdFusion, etc.), this answer may be inadequate, but let me take a stab nevertheless. First, if I understand you correctly, it's your working paradigm that's the problem. You're having developers make changes to files and then push them to three different sites. I suggest separating the development concerns altogether from the build/deploy concerns.

It sounds like you're using subrepositories in Mercurial to handle shared code--which is smart, by the way--so that's good. That takes care of sharing code across multiple projects. But rather than have each programmer pushing stuff to a given server after he updates it, have the programmers instead be pushing to some other "staging" repository. You could have one for each of your servers if you wish, though I think it probably makes more sense to keep all development in a single staging or "master" repository which is then used to build/deploy to your staging and/or live server.

If you wish to automate this process, there are a number of tools that can do this. I usually prefer NAnt with CruiseControl for build integration, but then my work is mostly .NET which makes it a great fit. If you can provide more specifics I can provide more details if you like, but I think the main problem for you to overcome is the way you're handling the workflow. Use Mercurial to keep multiple developers happy pulling/pushing from a single repository and then worry about deploying to your servers for testing as a separate step.

Comment: Hi - We're using LAMP (PHP).  We're doing our development on Windows PCs using Netbeans, and we set up the Linux development server as mapped drives.

Comment: so are you suggesting that there be a separate "master" repository for the shared subrepo, and that the developers push to that - and then a hook automatically pushes to all the different sites, and automatically updates as well?  What happens when there's a conflict on the development server?

Comment: Those details help. I rather suspected something like that. I'm suggesting that you have a single "master" repository for your shared code, which is used as a subrepository into another "master" repository for your developers to use as a target from which to clone their own sandbox copies. You should configure your tools, or find something like CruiseControl/Nant that will easily serve, to do a build, run your unit tests, and all that. Merge issues should be caught at this point, before anything is even deployed to the development server. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: so it looks like there is a PHP-friendly version of Ant called Phing - and this plays nice with CruiseControl - I'll look into it.

Comment: so if Programmer A pushes a change to the master subrepository - how does Programmer B get the code in a way that'll check for conflicts?  Won't he have to pull it three times - once for each site?  and won't Programmer A still have to do a pull in the subrepo of the other two site (this is on the dev server).

Comment: Programmer A pushes changes to a master repository. Programmer B pulls from that same repository. You may automate conflict resolution with tools I've suggested, or you can leave it to the programmers to resolve any conflicts. As to "three sites", correct me if I'm wrong but you're developing a single site, right? You're just deploying to three different servers: development, staging, production. So it's not like you need three different sites. You're deploying/promoting a single site. You can do that in Mercurial with labels, branches, etc. to keep the promotion levels straight.